# Webpack: Different behavior with 'vue init webpack' and 'vue init webpack-simple' project

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2

I'm quite new with Webpack and Vue.js.

We know that `vue-cli` bring with 2 project templates, `webpack` and `webpack-simple`.

When I use `webpack` template, If I want to use other package like `Bootstrap 4 beta`, I just need to do :

in `main.js`:

```
import 'jquery'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap'
```

In Webpack config:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
]
```

And Bootstrap works.

If I use `webpack-simple` template, I need to do this in `App.vue` to make Bootstrap work:

```
<style scoped>
    @import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
</style>
```

So if there are some options cause these differences?

I prefer `webpack-simple` to make my project simpler.

But I think this is the reason causes some other packages in my app not working properly (i.e. icons in `mavon-editor` does not displayed, but it works fine with `webpack` template).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid both ways are not the best for importing bootstrap.
try `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6`

and [follow the instructions](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#npm) in the site.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I did `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta`, and it's really not about this... thanks though

Comment: you are doing extra unnecessary work. the npm package solved the things you are trying to solve, like taking care of jquery dependency. they already did it for you, when you are using the package.

Comment: I did install the package by npm, just not the alpha version. My question is about import styles it to some pages of my app, not install the package to the project dir. I think maybe I just did not describe my problem clearly and you did not catch my problem. BTW npm solve most dependencies, but bootstrap is an exception, it just gives warning, but does not install jQuery and Popper.js.

Answer (score -1):

I compared the webpack config and `package.json` of both and find the answer.

The key point was a plugin called `style-loader`, actually `vue-style-loader` in Vue.js

which can:

> Adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a  tag

Install it by `npm install vue-style-loader --save-dev`

and edit webpack config from:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'css-loader'
  },
```

to:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'vue-style-loader'
      },
      {
        loader: 'css-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
```

Now the `css` files loads automatically, no need for `@import *.css` in `<style>` tag anymore.
And other third-party packages began working properly as well.